# Redux 'dispatch' function isn't called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import moment from "moment";
import firebaseApp from "../firestoreConfig";
import { config } from "../../App";
import FETCH_PRICES from "./types";

const firestore = firebaseApp.firestore();

export const getPrices = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    let prices;
    firestore
      .collection("settings-daily-market")
      .orderBy("MarketDate", "desc")
      .limit(1)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const Pd = doc.data().PdMarket;
          const Pt = doc.data().PtMarket;
          const Rh = doc.data().RhMarket;
          prices = { Pd, Pt, Rh };
          console.log(prices);
        });
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_PRICES, payload: prices });
        console.log("dispatched");
      });
  };
};
```

The console.log with the prices runs but the second console.log('dispatched') never does and the none of my reducer code for the "FETCH_PRICES" type runs. Instead I get an error:

"YellowBox.js:82 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?"

Why is dispatch() not working?

Comment: Looks like `FETCH_PRICES` does not have a type property. Can you post `./types`?

Comment: what is the value of `FETCH_PRICES` before the call to dispatch?

Comment: Thank you everyone! I was importing FETCH_PRICES incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure you want `import { FETCH_PRICES } from "./types";` since I can't imagine you exported FETCH_PRICES as default.

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you so much. This was the issue.